# Immortality Prescription

Tags: riddle

Your father is a scientist who has invented a red pill which, if eaten with 1 blue pill which he has invented, will grant immortality.

The night he invents it, he gives you 2 red and 2 blue pills just in case one of them is lost or substandard. He also warns you that an overdose will cause the opposite effect and kill you instead. You put the pills in your pocket and leave his lab for home.

On the way home, you are abducted by aliens who blindfold you and throw you into a singularity. At this point, you remember the pills your father gave you. You take them out (you can move and have enough oxygen in space for a short time), but realize that you can't tell the red pill from the blue pill. Even if you take off your blindfold, you can't see anything due to your proximity to the black hole.

**Given the circumstances, how do you successfully eat 1 red and 1 blue pill and survive?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just take

> 1/2 of every pill

Comment: I know this is the common solution, and one that I thought of, but amusingly in my head, it won't work.  It happens to be because the pills I'm taking, right now, are capsules, which cannot be split due to their design.  =D